# Angular: Directive watch model defined in own controller

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I try to update my chart when data is pushed to a websocket. I want to do this by defining my own directive in angular, but the binding of data does not work. The Code:

```js
angular.directive("myChart", ['service', function (service) {
    function ChartController ($scope) {
        var ws = new WebSocket("url/to/websocket/");
        var data = service.initData(); // initialize data table
        ws.onmessage = function (event) { // listen and update data
            data = service.updateData(event.data);
            $scope.recentData = data;
        }
        $scope.recentData = data;
    }

    function link(scope, element, attr) {
        function drawChart (data) {}

        scope.$watch('data', function (newD, old) {
            drawChart(newD);
        }, true);
    }
    return {link: link, controller: ['$scope', ChartController], restrict: 'EA'}  
}
```

Thats a simplistic example, of what i want to do. The service and data changes work well, i can log the current values. However `drawChart()` gets called only on startup and not on every mutation.

**The Controller has to be part of the directive and not wrapped around**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to notify angular of the changes by using a method that calls apply() after the change occurs, which is preferably done by using $timeout.

```
angular.directive("myChart", ['service', '$timeout', function (service, $timeout) {
function ChartController ($scope) {
    var ws = new WebSocket("url/to/websocket/");
    var data = service.initData(); // initialize data table
    ws.onmessage = function (event) { // listen and update data
        data = service.updateData(event.data);
        $scope.recentData = data;
    }
    $scope.recentData = data;
}

function link(scope, element, attr) {
    function drawChart (data) {}

    scope.$watch('data', function (newD, old) {
        $timeout(function(){
          drawChart(newD);
         });
    }, true);
}
return {link: link, controller: ['$scope', ChartController], restrict:     'EA'}  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the hint with the call to `apply()` really got me on my way